FFMPEG segment audio stream based on silence
I have a websocket connection that gets a stream of audio. I am piping the stream to FFMPEG and using it to segemnt the audio in real time. Currenlty the audio does get segemented but all the segemented audio is 10 seconds long rather than being segmented when silence is detected. I am using node.js typescript:
var proc = cp.spawn(ffmpeg, [
      '-f', 's16le',       // Input format: signed 16-bit little-endian PCM
    '-ar', '8000',       // Sample rate: 8000 Hz
    '-ac', '1',          // Audio channels: 1 (mono)
    '-i', '-',  '-af',
      'silencedetect=noise=-18dB:d=0.1', '-f',
      'segment', 
      '-segment_time', '10',
    '-reset_timestamps', '1',
      `${fileNameSubStringPath}_%03d.wav`
    ]);

I have tried changing the silencedetect values and the segment time. But notthing seems to work.
Is there a better way to segment audio based on silence?
